# "cron is not running" After runing a cron job from a Dockerfile

Tags: linux, docker, cron

I'm trying to do a hourly backup of a mysql database that is on a docker with a cronjob but when i build the docker and do `service cron status` it always says "cron is not running".

It ONLY works when i execute the command `service cron start` inside the docker but i cannot work with that.

My Dockerfile.mysql:

```
FROM ubuntu/mysql

COPY ./app/db/mydbname.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

# Add sql_backup file in the cron directory
ADD sql_backup /etc/cron.d/sql_backup

# Create the log file to be able to run tail
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

# Run the command on container startup
CMD crond -l 2 -f
```

sql_backup

```
* * * * * mysqldump -uroot -pmypassword mydb > /backups/mydbname.sql
* * * * * echo "Hello world" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
    db:
    image: ubuntu/mysql
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.mysql
    # NOTE: use of "mysql_native_password" is not recommended: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html#upgrade-caching-sha2-password
    # (this is just an example, not intended to be a production configuration)
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    network_mode: bridge
```

I have already tried to switch the last line of the DockerFile.mysql to `CMD ["cron", "-f"]` `CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log` etc.

Comment: Commands like `service` generally just don't work in Docker.  With the Dockerfile you show, if the container is successfully starting up, the cron daemon should be the _only_ thing running in its container; `docker exec your-container ps -e` should show just the `crond` process plus the debugging `ps`.

Comment: When i execute that command it just gives me the mysqld and the ps as you said.

Comment: How are you building and running the container?  (Looking at the first crontab line, you will need a `-h` option to point at the MySQL database container -- the cron container will _only_ run the cron daemon and not the database server.)

Comment: I updated the question with the docker-compose.yaml i use, but when im building i use the command `docker-compose build` in the folder of the docker and to run it i use `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml up`

Comment: The Compose `command:` overrides the image's `CMD`; that's why your various `CMD` changes are having no effect.  A container only runs one program, so you need two separate containers, one to run the database and a second one to run the cron jobs.

Comment: Ok, so i will divide the cronjob and mysql into two containers. By any chance do you know if the image `fradelg/docker-mysql-cron-backup` does that automatically? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Couldn´t have Cron and MySQL running on the same container. I have moved cron to another container and i have now the MySQL backups running.